# Pandas dict to dataframe - columns out of order?

Tags: python, pandas

I did a search but didn't see any results pertaining to this specific question. I have a Python dict, and am converting my dict to a pandas dataframe:

```
pandas.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

It works, with only one problem - the columns of my pandas dataframe are not in the same order as my Python dict. I'm not sure how pandas is reordering things. How do I retain the ordering?

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries (pre 3.6) are unordered so the column order can not be relied upon. You can simply set the column order afterwards.

```
In [1]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.rand(5),'b':np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[1]:
          a         b
0  0.512103 -0.102990
1  0.762545 -0.037441
2  0.034237  1.343115
3  0.667295 -0.814033
4  0.372182  0.810172
In [2]:

df = df[['b','a']]
df
Out[2]:
          b         a
0 -0.102990  0.512103
1 -0.037441  0.762545
2  1.343115  0.034237
3 -0.814033  0.667295
4  0.810172  0.372182
```

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionary is an unordered structure, and the key order you get when printing it (or looping over its keys) is arbitrary.

In this case, you would need to explicitly specify the order of columns in the DataFrame with,

```
pandas.DataFrame(data=data_dict, columns=columns_order)
```

where `column_order` is a list of column names in the order.

Comment: When trying this, I get the error 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'. I should say I am using pandas.DataFrame.from_dict now. If I run it using pandas.DataFrame, I get the error: 'ValueError: Shape of passed values is (13,), indices imply (13, 13)'

Comment: Won't this sort the columns alphabetically?

Comment: @JoshD. Yes it would. You can also order it any other way one likes.

Comment: @rth I guess my point is, the OP wants a specific order and your answer gives alphabetical (without explicitly specifying that's what it does), which is unlikely what they wanted.

Comment: @JoshD. Point taken. I have updated the formulation. Thanks.